# join Query to combine two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am looking for query to get output from two tables in a database as below,

```
table1-cities ---->   -------------   Table2----> -------------------------
                      |   City    |               | Person    |  City     |  
                      -------------               -------------------------
                      |   Delhi   |               |  Bob      |   Delhi   |
                      |   Mumbai  |               |  Alice    |   Delhi   |
                      |   Pune    |               |  Tim      |   Pune    |
                      -------------               -------------------------


    Output---->    ---------------------------
                   |   City  |  No.of persons |
                   ---------------------------  
                   |  Delhi  |      2         |
                   |  Mumbai |      0         |
                   |  Pune   |      1         |
                   ----------------------------
```

I tried somehow but I am not getting proper output.

So what should I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely.

Comment: Show us your current query! (Do you do GROUP BY?) Also, why do you store city names in two different tables?

Comment: Read on `LEFT JOIN`, `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: i tried with "select city,count(city) from table2 group by city"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Select c.city, COUNT(p.city) As 'No.of persons' from #cities c
Inner join #perrson p on c.city= p.city
group by c.city
```

For all zero values use left join

```
Select c.city, COUNT(p.city) As 'No.of persons' from #cities c
Left join #perrson p on c.city= p.city
group by c.city
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select c.City,
       count(p.City) as Number_OF_Persons
  from City as c
  left Join Person as p on c.City = p.City
 group by c.City
```

Answer (score 1):

try This..

```
    select t1.city,
           Count(t2.city) 
      from table1 t1
      left join table2 t2 on t2.city=t1.city
  group by t1.city
```

Comment: This will yield 1 for Mumbai. You need to specify a column of `Table2` for the parameter of COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- Use `Id` as primary key whenever possible.
- Create a foreign key constraint in Person's table that references the `City` table (Id).

You could use the left join to get what you want:

```
Select 
  c.city, 
  COUNT(p.cityId) "NoOfPerson" 
from 
   TabCity c
   left join TabPerson p on c.Id= p.cityId
group by 
    c.city
```

Here, `cityId` is foreign key column in `TabPerson` table and `c.Id` is primary key column in `TabCity` table

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't add conditions which might change the number of matching rows you can do the count before the join, which is usually more efficient:

```
Select 
  c.City, 
  COALESCE(p.cnt, 0) "No.of persons" -- change NULL to zero for missing cities
from cities c
left join
 (
   Select City, count(*) as cnt
   From persons
   Group by City
 ) p
on c.City= p.City
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Select City, Sum(Cnt) as NoOfPersons From
(Select City, count(*) as Cnt from Table1
Group By City
Union
Select City, count(*) as Cnt from Table2
Group By City)
Group By City
```

Comment: No. This gives you 3 for Delhi (1 because it is a city + 2 for two persons in the city). This is no query where UNION is appropriate and a GROUP BY on city in table1 makes no sense either, as this is the cities table which should hold each city exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

> i tried with "select city,count(city) from table2 group by city" –

This is okay, but not easy to read. As it is records you want to count per city, you should say so: `count(*)`. This query doesn't show Mumbai of course, as it is not in the table. In order to show Mumbai, too, you must include the cities table in your query. The easiest way is not to join the tables at all, but simply subselect the desired count:

```
select city, (select count(*) from table2 where table2.city = table1.city) as no_of_persons
from table1;
```

That would show you null for the Mumbai count. If you want zero instead, use COALESCE:

```
select 
  city, 
  coalesce((select count(*) from table2 where table2.city = table1.city),0) as no_of_persons
from table1;
```

As shown by others, you can also outer join table2 to table1 and then group and count. This is a bit error-prone, however, as you already see, because rather than using `count(*)` as you'd usually do when counting records, you must use `count(person)` (or `count(city)` for that matter), in order not to count outer-joined records.